# Notation for the pushforward measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, notation

Given a measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$, a measurable space $(Y,\Xi)$ and a measurable map $f\in\Sigma/\Xi$, the pushforward measure $\nu:=\mu\circ f^{-1}$ is given by
$$
  \nu[A] = \mu[f^{-1}(A)]
$$
for any $A\in \Xi$. That is, $f$ pushes $\mu$ from $(X,\Sigma)$ to $(Y,\Xi)$. The notation $\mu\circ f^{-1}$ is often used in probability theory, but it is not really convenient. I saw also a notation with an asterisk such as $\nu = f^*\mu$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401725/calculating-a-simple-integral-using-abstract-measure-theory) and $\nu = f_*\mu$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340180/change-of-variables-formula-for-riemann-integration-and-lebesgue-integration) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure). Since I have no much experience with pushforwards and pullbacks in other fields, I am not sure which of the notations is the right one: with an asterisk on the top or bottom. I would be happy if somebody clarifies this.

P.S. If one considers the category of measurable maps and stochastic (conditional) kernels as arrows, $f$ and $\mu$ are both special cases of arrows so actually in that notation it appears that
$$
  \nu = f\circ \mu
$$
which is very confusing taking into account the probabilistic variant $\nu = \mu\circ f^{-1}$.

I've found another notation $f_\#\mu$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257905/characterization-of-dirac-masses-on-c0-1-mathbbrd).

Comment: There is a general notational convention that a star upstairs denotes something contravariant, like a pull-back, an adjoint, and so on, i.e. something satisfying $(g\circ f)^\ast = f^\ast \circ g^\ast$, and a star downstairs means something covariant, like a push-forward, i.e., $(g \circ f)_\ast = g_\ast \circ f_\ast$.

Comment: @Martin: I see, so in the case of OP one shall use $f_*$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I would use and that's what I'm used to in connection with measures. However, I don't know what probabilists use, hence only a coment. // By the way: you look like Vyacheslav Tikhonov :-)

Comment: @Martin: that's indeed his photo :) I was looking for good photos of Shtirlitz, with no nazi uniform (not to be misunderstood), and that one appeared to me the best. Btw, have you seen notation $f_\#\mu$ (I added a link in OP)?

Comment: It's a good choice :-) // I don't think I've seen $f_{\#} \mu$ for measures, but in other contexts. I guess it would be an acceptable choice. In my view of the meaning of notation, the more important aspect than the symbol is whether it is a subscript or a superscript, partly for the reason explained in my first comment.

Comment: @Martin: I see :) // how do you know Tikhonov?

Comment: For some reason I don't remember I happened to come across the Isaev series and read a few of those novels. Out of curiosity, I watched a bit of the TV show.

Comment: What"s wrong with $\nu = \mu\circ f^{-1}$? It is after all the composition of the measure with the function $f^{-1}$ that maps sets to preimages.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: it is not very convenient when you have to deal with compositions of functions $f\circ g\circ h$ and when you need to consider $\nu$ as a function of $\mu$.

Comment: I've seen all of the following been used: $\mu\circ f^{-1}$, $\mu_f$ and $f(\mu)$. However, I prefer using the first my self.