# Function/Measure Notation in Geometric Measure Theory

Tags: measure-theory, functions, notation, geometric-measure-theory

I'm trying to understand a formula of this kind
$$
...=\phi_\sharp \left ( f \mathcal{H}^n    \right )
$$
where $\mathcal{H}^n$ is the n-dimensional Hausdorff measure on a measure space $X$, $\phi : X \to Y$ ($Y$ also a measure space) and $\phi_\sharp$ is the pushforward. Also $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$.

Recall that the definition of pushforward requires "$f \mathcal{H}^n$" to be a measure (see for instance GMT of Mattila, definition 1.17).

My question is: how do I actually read the notation "$f \mathcal{H}^n$"? And where can I find references about it?

By definition of pushforward, for $A \subseteq Y$, we have immediately
$$
\left [ \phi_\sharp \left ( f \mathcal{H}^n    \right ) \right ](A) = \left [ f \mathcal{H}^n \right ] \left ( \phi^{-1}(A) \right )
$$
but that is as far as I go.

PS$1$: I already read this but it didn't help much: [Notation for the pushforward measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403062/notation-for-the-pushforward-measure)

PS$2$: since this is a notational question, feel free to change some of the setting if it can help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Usually, if $\mu $ is a measure and $f $ is a function, then $f\mu $ is the measure given by
$$
(f\mu)(A) =\int_A f \, d\mu.
$$

This is indeed a measure as long as $f \in L^1 (\mu)$ or if $f : X \to [0,\infty] $.